# how to get flavor name on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to get flavor name Flutter side? for both android and ios

**build.gradle**

```
flavorDimensions "app"

productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "app"
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    qa {
        dimension "app"
        applicationId "com.demo.qa"
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a main purpose of getting flavor name? Use different configuration based on flavor name in the dart code? Or you just want to get flavor name?

Answer (score 31):

As long as every flavor has a different packageName you could do it like this:

```
enum EnvironmentType { dev, qa }

class Environment {
  EnvironmentType current;

  Environment() {
    PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      switch (packageInfo.packageName) {
        case "com.demo.qa":
          current = EnvironmentType.qa;
          break;
        default:
          current = EnvironmentType.dev;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but packag_info was replaced by a community version that depends on fullter framework and can't run as the first line in main

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem as you could just instantiate the class after Flutter is loaded. 
One possibility would be to add a TransitionBuilder to the MaterialApp and setup your dependencies there.

Comment: I needed it to init Sentry logging - it needs to be way before the UI

Comment: Note this doesn't work on web. Use Till Friebe's solution instead.

Answer (score 31):

You could use the solution from [jonahwilliams](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31441#issuecomment-598011001).

1. Set a key-value pair when creating the app:

```sh
flutter build apk --flavor=paid --dart-define=app.flavor=paid
```

2. Access the value in Dart:

```dart
const String flavor = String.fromEnvironment('app.flavor');

void main() {
  print(flavor);
}
```

This would print "paid" when run.

The advantages are that you can use this on platforms where flavors are not supported yet and that the variable is `const`.
The disadvantage that you have to set the key-value pair for the build.

Comment: This is exactly what I used. Works great when building for android because you can pass it with the shell command. Still need to know how to pass dart-define when building an archive from xcode.

Comment: @shadysamir it's similar to above when building from the command line. `flutter build ipa --flavor=paid --dart-define=app.flavor=paid` This link will help a bit. https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios

Comment: @nick yeah shell build archive was not released yet in stable back then. But it's been for a while now.

Comment: I guess, there are many benefit that we can handle flavor type as `const` like set default value of freezed field or function default arguments.

Answer (score 15):

If you've setup your flavors like it is shown in [the official Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors) you can use the globally available `appFlavor` variable to access the flavor name you defined with `--flavor` upon running the app. `appFlavor` variable is part of *services.dart* library. You can access it by importing the library:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Now you can use it in your code like this:

```
if (appFlavor == 'prod') {
    // do something
  }
```

---

EXPLANATION:

The *flavor.dart* within services.dart contains the following code:

```
const String? appFlavor = String.fromEnvironment('FLUTTER_APP_FLAVOR') != '' ?
  String.fromEnvironment('FLUTTER_APP_FLAVOR') : null;
```

This means that it's not necessary to define the flavor anywhere else one more time or use `--dart-define` to define the flavor. The parameter you provide to `--flavor` is automatically dart-defined under FLUTTER_APP_FLAVOR key and can be accessed in the same way as shown in the *flavor.dart*.

Comment: Just what i was looking for, thanks

Comment: This should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 6):

I haven't seen any answer describing how to get the current flavor directly from runtime config, after a lot of search I found this way:
For Android is quite simple, put this code in your MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
    private val CHANNEL = "flavor_channel"

  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "getFlavor" -> {
                    result.success(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)
                }
            }
    }
  }
```

For iOS, put that in the AppDelegate.swift:

```
let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
let flavorChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "flavor_channel",
                                          binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
flavorChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
  (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
  // This method is invoked on the UI thread.
  guard call.method == "getFlavor" else {
    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    return
  }
  self.receiveCurrentFlavor(result: result)
})
```

Then create this method at the bottom of AppDelegate class:

```swift
    private func receiveCurrentFlavor(result: FlutterResult) {
    var config: [String: Any]?
        
    if let infoPlistPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Info", withExtension: "plist") {
        do {
            let infoPlistData = try Data(contentsOf: infoPlistPath)
            
            if let dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: infoPlistData, options: [], format: nil) as? [String: Any] {
                config = dict
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    result(config?["Flavor"])
  }
```

We now need to make the Flavor available in the infoDictionary. In Xcode, open Runner/Info.plist and add a key Flavor mapped to ${PRODUCT_FLAVOR}:
[image: info.plist]

Now, under Targets/Runner/Build Settings/User-Defined and add a setting PRODUCT_FLAVOR. Add the flavor name for each configuration:
[image: User-Defined settings]

Then in Dart:

```dart
final flavor =  await const MethodChannel("flavor_channel").invokeMethod("getFlavor");
```

Then you're done!

Comment: Great answer. I was missing the step of adding "Flavor" to Info.plist

Answer (score 4):

Just write a channel method for that.

```kotlin
 override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "getFlavor" -> {
                    result.success(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Than in dart:

```dart
final flavor = await platform.invokeMethod("getFlavor");
```

Comment: your answer should contain code to setup the method channel on ios as well since the OP asked "for both android and ios".

Comment: This worked nice for me. Thanks! =^,^=

Answer (score 3):

There is not a simple way to know the flavor name, however I would suggest you to use an environment variable, loaded from [flutter_dotenv](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv) for example.

file .env

```
FLAVOR=dev
```

file main.dart

```
void main() async {
  await DotEnv().load('.env');
  final flavor = DotEnv().env['FLAVOR'];

  String baseUrl;
  if (flavor == 'dev') {
    baseUrl = 'https://dev.domain.com';
  } else if (flavor == 'qa') {
    baseUrl = 'https://qa.domain.com';
  } else {
    throw UnimplementedError('Invalid FLAVOR detected');
  }
}
```

This will allow you (as developer) to easily change the behaviour of your app and switch from different environments seamlessy.

Comment: That does not load a different config file based on flavour so it does not help