# how to build multiple apps with slightly different UI from one project in flutter

Tags: flutter

My query is how can we build multiple apps with different UI's from one project.
Example:

`HomePage` has (`home1, home2, home3`) 3 different Ui's , i want to add `home1` for one app,  `home2` for other app and so on.

So that i can create similar apps with slightly different UI.

How can we configure the same in flutter?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004302/how-do-you-pass-arguments-from-command-line-to-main-in-flutter-dart

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flavors](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors) for it. In few words, you should create a project with common features and separate it by packages (because Google Play doesn't support apps with the same package name). Your features and different screens (and icons and other app specific resources) separated in flavors, and when you build specific flavor - you build separated app (in your case). In code you can split features by flavor type (find more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60610270) question).

Comment: Thanks fartem, Can you help me with some design examples.

Comment: flavors is an old and nor convenient way, the better way is to use environment variables

Comment: @SurajGupta By [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors) link you can find how to implement flavors in your app.